# the table identifier does not refer to an existing ETS table

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

In a GenServer

```
  def init(_opts \\ []) do
    table = :ets.new(:my_table, [:duplicate_bag, :public])
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def add_player(zone_id, socket_id) do
    :ets.thing(
      :my_table,
      {some_key, [my_uuid]}
    )
  end
```

But I get `the table identifier does not refer to an existing ETS table`

It's a public table, and I know init is getting called before the test executes because I logged in there.

I'm not sure why ets is doing this.

Answer (score 4):

In order to reference the table by its name, you need to make it a named table when creating it:

```
    table = :ets.new(:my_table, [:duplicate_bag, :public, :named_table])
```

Without `:named_table`, you need to use the reference returned by `:ets.new` to access the table.

(Also note that the table will be deleted if the process that created it dies, but that doesn't seem to be what's happening here.)

Comment: It’s worth adding that `add_player/2` being exported might provoke its explicit call from outside the process, making `:public` definition of the table crucial.